# c# Generics help - how to pass params to new T()

Tags: c#, generics, abstract-class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create instance of generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731452/create-instance-of-generic-type)

How can I pass a param to a generic contstructor?

```
 public class Payment<T>  where T: HostFunctionContext, IClaimPayment, new()  
{

    public IResultEntity Display(MyUser user, string claim, int? cert)
    {
        **HostFunctionContext func = new T(user) as HostFunctionContext;**  <~doesn't compile        
        IClaimPayment payment = new T();
        payment.ClaimNumber = claimNumber;
        payment.CertificateSequence = certSequence;

        return payment.DisplayEntity();

    }
```

}

```
 public sealed partial class CardPayment : HostFunctionContext
{
    public CardPayment(MyUser user) : base(user) { }
```

}

constructor for abstract HostFunctionContext

```
public HostFunctionContext(MyUser user) {

        _hostConnection = HostConnectionAssembler.GetHostConnection();
        _functionParams = FunctionParamsAssembler.GetFunctionParams();
        if (user != null) {
            _hostConnection.Login = user.Login;

        }
    }
```

I need to pass the user to the baseclass of T. How can I do this? Do I create a parameterless constructor, then a property of type MyUser, then on the set of that property push that to the baseclass? The abstract baseclass has no myUser property and no parameterless constructor. I am really stuck here.

Thanks for any help,
~ck

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/731452/create-instance-of-generic-type

Answer (score 3):

The new() keyword by definition restricts your generic parameter to be a reference type with a public, parameterless constructor.  When you instantiate a "new T()", it has to use reflection to create an instance of it.

You may want to use a factory pattern to create your objects instead of trying to do it through a generic constructor.  You could pass the type into the factory and have the factory logic pass you back the correct object type, initialized with the user.

Comment: Why would a compiler have to use reflection?

Comment: Who said anything about the compiler?  See here for a good explanation:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367577/why-does-the-c-compiler-emit-activator-createinstance-when-calling-new-in-with-a

Comment: @David B: Because there's nothing built into IL to express "construct a new instance of this type parameter using a parameterless constructor".

Comment: I guess "it" in my post is ambiguous.  I see how you interpreted that.  I'll try an edit.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried this myself but surely (for the right type) you could just use properties on the interface to get what you need?

```
T foo = new T{ Prop1="BAR", Prop2="BAZ" }
```

Comment: T would have to expose those properties through an interface which is supplied as part of the constraints, but that might work.

Comment: Oh yeah, "use properties on the interface" - I assume that the OPs IClaimPayment has these or can be extended to have them.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a base parameterless constructor, you're not going to be able to use generics like that. One option is to require the Payment constructor to receive "instructions" for how to build its `T`, via a delegate:

```
public class Payment<T> where T: HostFunctionContext, IClaimPayment
{
    private Func<MyUser, T> ContextBuilder { get; set; }
    public Payment(Func<MyUser, T> contextBuilder)
    {
        ContextBuilder = contextBuilder;
    }

    public IResultEntity Display(MyUser user, string claim, int? cert)
    {
        T context = ContextBuilder(user);

        IClaimPayment payment = context as IClaimPayment;
        payment.ClaimNumber = claimNumber;
        payment.CertificateSequence = certSequence;

        return payment.DisplayEntity();
    }
}

// Usage:
var MyCreditPayment = new Payment<CreditPayment>(user => new CreditPayment(user));
```

There are other patterns to achieve this, but ultimately you're going to need some way to encapsulate how your context gets created.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx).  You can pass arguments into the constructor this way.