# Is a variant of this possible with C# Generics?

Tags: c#, generics

Am i trying to achieve the impossible or is it simply unnecessary? The code in GetList is the same for all specializations of the class A, apart from the bit to create a new instance of the specialization. There is no default constructor, always the same list of parameters.

At the moment I am using instead  `public static List<A> GetList(int i, Func<A> createMeAnInstance)`

Which feels unclean.

```
abstract class A
{
  protected A (int i)
  {

  }

  public static List<T> GetList<T>(int i) where T : A
  {
    var list = new List<T>();
    for(int x = 1; x< 100; x++)
    {
     var o = new T(i);
     list.Add(o);
    }
  }
 }   

 public class B : A
 {
    public B (int i) : base(i) {}
 }

 ...

 var list = A.GetList<B>(1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call parameterized constructors on generic types. Your **Func<>** version is the best approach here.

Answer (score 3):

Operator `new` compiles as call `Activator.CreateInstance`.

Just write

> Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new object[] {i})

not perfect but works.

Comment: No, it doesn't compile as a call to `Activator.CreateInstance`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367577/why-does-the-c-compiler-emit-activator-createinstance-when-calling-new-in-with-a

Comment: I'm tempted to mark this one as correct. Seems the cleanest to me. Sending in a instantiating code as a parameter doesnt seem DRY to me. Any comments as to Func param vs Activator.CreateInstance ?

Comment: Activator.CreateInstance is slow, but with Func you actually specifies creation of object outside of your function. It's an arbitary decision depending on your problem.

Comment: @gandjustas: ok, you were right and I apologize. Thanks for the link, it was new for me

Comment: I've marked this up as its an option and not incorrect, but I've chosen the delegate approach - it might not be dry but Its safer IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. You only can specify `new()` as a type constraint for constructors.

Why don't you take the `B` instance directly in `GetList`?

```
List<B> list = A.GetList(new B(i));
```

Use this code:

```
public static List<T> GetList<T>(T o) where T : A
{
    var list = new List<T>();
    list.Add(o);
    return list;
}
```

Comment: well are u saying GetList(Func<A> code) or GetList(A a) ? The latter doesnt work for me

Comment: added a for loop which hopefully highlights why i need a delegate and not a literal.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly...
You can create an instance of T by reflecting it's constructors, or using the Activator.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use default constructor and move i to the base class (A) as a field.
But in some situations it could be more appropriate to use reflection